# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

> Вы можете использовать любой телефон на базе Android, или iOS, или Windows Phone.

Правильно ведь расставлены запятые перед двумя союзами, соединяющими однородные члены предложения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все правильно. Смотрим [здесь](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=zap&text=19_27):

§ 147. Запятая ставится между всеми однородными членами предложения и в том случае, когда только часть их имеет впереди себя повторяющиеся союзы, например:
Татьяна верила преданьям простонародной старины, и снам, и карточным гаданьям, и предсказаниям луны.
Пушкин

Буду ли я пеною в море, или голубою мглой на горах, или вечерней тенью степной – я всегда буду помнить о тебе.
М. Горький

Comment: А ведь при союзе ли.. или запятая не нужна, не так ли? 

Играешь ли ты сегодня или делаешь уроки? 

Правильно ли я расставил знаки препинания?

Comment: ли это не союз, а частица, поэтому на нее не распространяются правила для союзов

Comment: Да знаю я, что ли –– это частица. Я говорю про другое.

Comment: ну раз знаете об этом, то и вопрос должен быть исчерпан. в приведенном вами примере однородные члены соединены одним союзом "или", поэтому запятая не нужна